# tikzcd : how to extended triangle with more arrows?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, tikz-cd, tikz-graphs

I have the following code which produces the attached triangle picture.  Does anyone know how to produce a directed edge from S_0, down and to the right, ending at D_0b?  Also, join vertexes S_1 and S_1 into a single vertex or point?

The tikz-cd documentation had little info on this shape and my own results led to many compilation failures.  Appreciate any guidance on creating the shape.

Thanks

Note: I'm attempting to draw a Porphyry tree.

```
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny]
    & S_0 \arrow[dd, "\phi_1" description] \\
    D_0 \arrow[ur, leftarrow] \arrow[dr, "\phi_2" description] \\
    & S_1 \\
    & S_1 \arrow[dd, "\phi_1" description] \\
    D_1 \arrow[ur, leftarrow] \arrow[dr, "\phi_2" description] & \\
    & S_2
  \end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Perhaps I'm a bit slow, but I don't quite understand your first point. How should that edge look exactly?  For the second point, simply delete the third row in your matrix, the one containing just ```& S_1 \\```.

Comment: I corrected the description. The edge should go from S_0 to D_0b on the right.  D_0b does not exist in the above picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renewed answer after OP's clarification:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny]
    & S_0 \arrow[dd, "\phi_1" description]\ar[dr] \\
    D_0 \arrow[ur, leftarrow] \arrow[dr, "\phi_2" description] &&D_{0b}\\
    & S_1 \arrow[dd, "\phi_1" description]\ar[dr] \\
    D_1 \arrow[ur, leftarrow] \arrow[dr, "\phi_2" description] &&D_{1b}\\
    & S_2
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good except I need to add a label to the right vertex at the end of the right edge. D0b. Then add the same below as another right edge to label D1b. I will try this. Thanks for interpreting this!

Comment: @Nick See my renewed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny]
    & S_0\dlar \ar[dd, "\phi_1" description] \drar \\
    D_0 \drar["\phi_2" description] & & D_{0b}\\
    &S_1\dlar \arrow[dd, "\phi_1" description] \\
    D_1 \drar["\phi_2" description] & \\
    & S_2
  \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I vote you but apparently the question is not very clear. Your doubt has confirmed my hypothesis of unclearness.

Comment: Let's hope theO.P. will post some clarification!. I think the image is scanned from book, as it can't result from the posted code.

Comment: It could be because the characters are those of newtx package in text and/or mathematical mode.

Comment: The image resulted from the posted code. I have a lot of packages included also some for Greek text, which may substitute fonts from the system rather then ams ones.

Comment: This looks correct except it needs a directed edge to the right with a label. I did not clarify this in the original post and updated accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @Nick: I've updated my answer with your clarification.

Comment: Thanks.  Both were correct.  I marked the first correct because it had the partial answer first.

Comment: That's no problem. @CarLaTeX has a crystal ball that I don't have to guess ;o)